# Where I can find sharepoint api

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I am new one to sharepoint. I want to gather all the methods and class available in sharepoint. Where I can get them. Just like API. I searched with Sharepoint API in google. But results are not much pretty match. Can you please suggest me any link or document in which i have all the methods and classes for sharepoint.

Thanks

Comment: SharePoint has a Server Object Model, a Client Object Model (in several flavors), and a few other things you might consider to be an "API". The fact that you're asking this question shows how far off you are. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537564, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776256 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557253.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one [Link](http://www.cozyroc.com/category/tags/api)

These contains some of the classes and methods

Answer (score 0):

This should have what you're looking for:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557253.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The main part of the SharePoint API is located in the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll. All classes there are up to your disposition =).
Another part of the SharePoint API is located here c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI. All the ddls contain some API for a certain part of SharePoint.
Moreover there are asmx and svc services that are also located there and they provide more API to SharePoint. And there are also certain assmeblies and services in the GAC and other locations that also provide APIs to other parts of SharePoint.

As you can see the API is really broad and efforts you're gonna spend trying to document them all are enormous. I doubt if they are really documented properly by Microsoft for public use. So now you probably realize why google gave you nothing on SharePoint API. I hope I answered your actual question but I still cannot imagine why you need such a document. If you need it to solve some problem with it, it is definitely not the best way to go. So post here your actual problem so we could help.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I dont know how much big it is. thats why asking. Any way thanks :))